# Excel Data, Why does formula change dd/mm/yyyy to #####

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the date 10/10/2018 in cell A2. In B2 I have `=A2&" Total"` which comes as 43383 Total. But for my vlookup I need it in 10/10/2018 format.

How can I format this to stay at dd/mm/yyyy?

I have tried formatting cells but does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use TEXT to format the date before the concatenation:

```
=TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy") & " Total"
```